# MPR121 sensor sensitivity

Tags: touch, i2c, arduino-ide, micropython, arduino-esp32

I have connected and tested the two break-board versions of MPR121 Proximity Capacitive Touch Sensor Controller with various mcu's (ESP32, RPI pico, ARDUINO)
The one on a keypad version (Sparkfun compatible) and the one that you can connect custom pads to it. I tried them both with cpp and micropython. I connected them via I2C and everything is functioning on all occasions, with the IRQ option as well.
However I have trouble increasing sensitivity and by that I mean that if I place even a thin piece of paper or other layer before the touch pads, I can't get a touch signal.
Looking into the MPR121 micropython example Library I modified the following:

MicroPython MPR121 capacitive touch keypad and breakout board driver
[https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-mpr121](https://MicroPython%20MPR121%20capacitive%20touch%20keypad%20and%20breakout%20board%20driver)

Inside this library I see the following parameters for tuning that I tried:

```
# Set touch and release trip thresholds
#self.set_thresholds(15, 7)  default....
self.set_thresholds(15, 7)

# Set config registers
# Debounce Touch, DT=0 (increase up to 7 to reduce noise)
# Debounce Release, DR=0 (increase up to 7 to reduce noise) .....default was 0x00
self._register8(MPR121_DEBOUNCE, 0x00)

# First Filter Iterations, FFI=0 (6x samples taken)
# Charge Discharge Current, CDC=16 (16uA) .default was 0x10 5-30 less to more sensitive
self._register8(MPR121_CONFIG1, 0x30)

# Charge Discharge Time, CDT=1 (0.5us charge time)
# Second Filter Iterations, SFI=0 (4x samples taken)
# Electrode Sample Interval, ESI=0 (1ms period) .default was 0x20 5-30 less to more sen
self._register8(MPR121_CONFIG2, 0x20)
```

I tried various combinations but the effect is minimal if non-existent. My target or best case scenario is to be able to place a 3mm plexiglass on top of the breakout board or custom pads.

Comment: So what is your programming question ?

Comment: If it is a software issue, am i looking at the right parameters in the library? Has anybody from the community faced the same issue and was able to solve it in the code?